# If/Else statement checking if argument is supplied

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am working on simplifying my Git workflow, I have a shell function that adds, commits, and pushes a file when supplied with a file name. However, I am trying to add an if/else statement within the function to check if a filename argument is supplied with the function call. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sendit (){
        local filename="$1"

        if [[ -z "$filename" ]]; then
                echo "No filename supplied."
                return 1
        else
                git add "$filename"
                read -p "Commit description: " desc
                git commit -m "$desc"
                git push origin master
        fi
}
```

When I run `sendit [filename]` everything works fine, however when I run the function without the filename, I am still being prompted to add a commit description instead of exiting.

Comment: This file needs to be sourced in to be activated -- despite the presence of a shebang, just executing it as a subprocess will have no effect. Are you sure it's been sourced in? That is to say, in your interactive shell, does running `type sendit` emit the code from your question (as opposed to an earlier version without the `if`)?

Comment: You can see that the code works perfectly as given in the question at https://ideone.com/W7Krn3 (exiting with an error as intended instead of prompting).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is sourced. As I have mentioned in my question, It works just fine when a filename is supplied, however the if/else statement to check if the filename is supplied or not doesn't seem to be working. To sum it up, when the function is ran with a filename it works, when no filename is supplied it still continues with going to the commit description part of the code.

Comment: See link. I don't believe your claim that you actually sourced the exact version given in the question.

Comment: ...if you want to provide evidence for that claim, run `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}+'; set -x; sendit; set +x` and edit the trace log generated into the question. This will let us know exactly what was *actually* assigned to `filename`, and thus determine why it's detected as nonempty -- if the code run does in fact match that which is stated.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can not believe me or not, but I had just checked that it is sourced and when I run ``` type sendit ``` it does emit the updated code. This is why I am stumped and therefore posted the question.

Comment: Again: `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}+'; set -x; sendit; set +x`

Comment: Running the above: ```::42+sendit
:main.sh:1+git add ''
fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths
:main.sh:2+read -p 'Commit description: ' desc
Commit description: ^C
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211680/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-meager-data).

Comment: Some reason, restarting the system has fixed whatever the issue was.

Comment: @meager-data : BTW, an ìf` is not necessary in your special case. If you assigne as `local filename=${1:?No filename supplied}`, it will work too (printing an error message and exiting).

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you, that is very helpful. I tried it and it does do as you say. I am new to shell scripting.